# Spring Annotation: @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i want to make somethings clear about @Transactional spring annotation.
Suppose i have written my code something as under,
case-1

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class) 
public void method1(){
.....method body....
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class) 
public String method2(){
try{
method1()
}
catch(Exce...){

}

}
```

case 2:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class) 
public void method1(){
 try{
 }
catch(Excep..){
}
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class) 
public String method2(){

method1()
}
```

What would happen in case-1 if some exception occurs in excecution of method1, does it rollback transaction?
and what would happen for the same in case-2.
Thanx in advance

Comment: I suppose that the question is what happens when you are calling method2()?

Comment: Do you really need _method2()_ in your example?

Comment: @ mina - Yes i need this method, because method1 is scheduled using @Scheduled annotation, so method1 can not have return type, it should be void only and i need to send message to client. Thats why i called method1 from method 2 to send message.

Comment: It's just me being too much on EL&U or your are asking about what happens when _method1()_ is executed?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what my question is, but these are two scenarios i want to know about.

Comment: So **Why** post method2() in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no rollback in any of your use cases regardless of the exception type or propagation as long as you catch the exception in `method2`.

*Why?*

Spring creates a proxy class for the `Transactional` class or members, this is not visible for you. This proxy makes it possible to Spring to execute code before and after your function, basically open transaction, commit or rollback. This proxy is injected into your classes when you autowire them.

Of course the `Transactional` annotations only work when you're calling them **through the proxy**!

Your `method1` call is always a local function call, so as long as you catch the exception in `method2` it won't cause any rollback.

But please read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

Comment: @shlomi33 - if it works for Error then it should also work for any exception,right? And if not, then why?

Comment: java.lang.Error is not a child of java.lang.Exception and so it will not be caught in the catch block so the f/w will rollback for such a case

Comment: I duplicated the *as long as you catch the exception in `method2`* sentence because I believe the OP was curious to the transactional behaviour between functions, but of course, if `method2` throws an unchecked exception that will end in rollback.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to specify. Using annotations for instance you can write like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, timeout=10)
```

Default behavior is not to rollback when an exception is thrown across the transaction demarcation line.

Comment: I have written @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class) on both methods. What would happen in both the cases then?

Comment: @user3404577 I see that you did not post exactly what you've configured... Can you update the question so we'll have the whole picture?!

Answer (score 0):

The Spring `@Transactional` default configuration (as you used it here) is rolling back only for `java.lang.RuntimeException` s and the propagation is `REQUIRED`.

So in case you are calling method2():

1. CASE 1: no rollback as you are catching in method2() `java.lang.Exception` (which is the parent of `java.lang.RuntimeException`)
2. CASE 2: same - as you are catching in method1() `java.lang.Exception`

The meaning of the propagation here is that when you've started a transaction if you encounter another annotation of @Transaction another transaction is not started and the application uses the "outer" transaction. So do not expect that the rollback logic will get executed before the method2() finishes. Anyway, one may assume from your snippet that the methods are in the same Spring Bean so calling a method internally in a bean (method2() calls method1() here) the AOP annotation are not "active" meaning that the f/w will not even "see" the @Transactionl on method1().

EDIT

Question changed so that the rollback is for all `java.lang.Throwable` s. So the answer is the same except for the fact that if an `java.lang.Error` is thrown then there is a rollback in both cases after the method2() is finished.

Comment: It doesnt rollback transaction in case-2. I havnt checked case-1 yet.

Comment: I said that it will in case of an Error as in java.lang.Error